# extraction using regex to get domainname url and username

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract domain, url and username from the below set of events.

For eg: Domain need to be http://damtare.by.ru
 URL need to be http://damtare.by.ru/id.txt
name - emaxwell (name from the email id)

Event

```
\d+.\d+\s\d+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\d+\s+GET\s(?<domain>http:\/\/[^ \/]+)(?<url>(\S+))\s+(?<user>[^@]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/52GMc4/5/

My regex is not extracting the URL properly. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You started your `url` group after the end of the `domain` group. Try this: [`(?<url>(?<domain>http:\/\/[^ \/]+)\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/mn9JQ0/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the this: [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/52GMc4/6)

Basically I moved your 'url' Group BEFORE the 'domain' Group and added the user at the end.
BTW: Your url contains a Space, not allowed!